# How to have multiple windows in one WPF Application?

Tags: wpf

I'm relatively new to the WPF world and I'm working on an application where I need to have multiple windows in one application. Like Photoshop when the user clicks on "New" button a new window opens and the old existing window(s) goes in the background. The toolbar and the statusbar, however, stay on top, untouched. 
I would also like to add the feature that the user can work with multiple windows if each of them is not maximized.
How do I achieve this?
I apologize if I'm a bit unclear in framing my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are (probably) talking about is an MDI Application.  "Unfortunately" WPF does not support that natively.  I use quotes because it is more frowned upon in modern UI development than it was in the past.

Instead, the most common "WPF way" of doing this is to open each New window in a new tab in a tab control (like Visual Studio and most web browsers do).

If you really want to do an MDI application, [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=WPF+MDI+Application) that, but to warn you, it probably means creating your own Window manager.

An alternative is to open non-modal windows, with their ShowInTaskbar property set to false.  This gives you the ability to open as many windows as you want, but you lose the ability to contain them within a centralized workspace app.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I never thought of a tabbed application. That will work perfectly in the given context. Thanks again :)